# Where to upload conference posters and how to share them?

Tags: open-access, poster, backup-archiving

When presenting a scientific poster at a conference, I am often asked by colleagues if they can get a copy of the poster. Often, I have DIN A4 prints ready (quite hard to read...) and I am also happy to share them via email, if somebody is interested.

It would all be much easier if I could just upload the poster to some *open repository* where it is archived such that I just need to share a link.

Neither arXiv seems to be the right place for it, nor figshare. Is there some open repository for scientific posters which I missed so far?

Comment: I like to post them on figshare. Why not?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson so far, I only used figshare for data/results and videos (visualizing results). I've never seen someone use figshare for conference posters (you are the first one), but maybe I missed that...?

Comment: @Alf I also use figshare for posters. Now you know of two.

Comment: @Gimelist they are spreading!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any open repository that hosts research posters. But, some conferences do upload a pdf copy of all accepted posters to their website so you can check the venue where you presented your work to see if they offer something similar.

Another option which I see all the time is uploading the poster to your personal website or the website associated with your research group or lab. These websites always have a publications link that usually includes a subsection for poster publications.

Comment: good point, a few conferences deposit indeed pdf copies of the posters on their website (an exception, though, in my community).  I like your second idea, talk my boss into providing a posters section on our website (so far, only peer-reviewed publications appear there)

Answer (score 3):

ResearchGate lets you add posters (including the file) to your profile.

It even lets you generate DOIs for these research items, although they mention that this should only be done for unpublished research and they consider posters as published research. However, you can add the DOI from the book of abstracts (if you got one) and imo it would be at least technically possible to assign a DOI to the poster if it doesn't have one but you should check with the conference, and possibly researchgate, f that's fine with them.

Comment: I didn't knew about ResearchGate's option to generate DOIs, but ResearchGate is not really an option for me (due to all the copyright issues there which I do not have at "real" Open Repositories).

Answer (score 2):

I usually upload posters to my own website. Then I add a short link and a QR code to the bottom of the poster saying "Scan here for PDF of poster".

Comment: that has been exactly my approach so far. I would, however, prefer something more persistent and also something which I can recommend our new students to do (I can hardly expect them to have their own webspace)